# Image should show when input fields are filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ive been stuck a couple days on writing my code for a school project. this is my code:

```
**HTML**
 <fieldset id="step1">
<legend>Step 1</legend>
<p1>How many people will be attending?</p1>
 <div id="selected_form_code">
 <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">Please choose</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
  <div class="Attendees" id="form1">
      <h2 id="infoNames">Please provide full names:</h2>
      <form action="#" id="form_submit" method="post" name="form_submit">
          <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee1" name="a">
              <label>
                  Attendee 1 name:
                  <input>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee2" name="b">
              <label>
                  Attendee 2 name:
                  <input>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee3" name="c">
              <label>
                  Attendee 3 name:
                  <input>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee4" name="d">
              <label>
                  Attendee 4 name:
                  <input>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee5" name="e">
              <label>
                  Attendee 5 name:
                  <input>
              </label>
          </div>

     </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <p class="vinkje"><img src="vinkje.png" height="100" width="100"></p>
 </fieldset>
```

this is a selector which will drop down the forms as which input u choose. But now i have to get an image when all of these inputs are filled in. here is my jq code:

```
function checkInput() {
if (!$('Attendee1').val())
    $('.vinkje').hide();
}
```

this is the code that i have used for the dropdown menu, where u can choose the amount of forms u want to append

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var isEmpty = true;
$('.vinkje').hide();
hideInput();
$('#select_btn').change(function() {
    hideInput();
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
    if (sel_value == 0) {
        hideInput();
    } else {
        $("#infoNames").show();
        for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++) {
            $("#Attendee" + i).show();
        }
    }
    checkInput();
});

$('.Attendees input').blur(function()
{
    checkInput();
});


});
```

Comment: I don't see any usage of checkInput here?

Comment: Because Attendee1 is an ID you should target it with the # symbol, like so: $('#Attendee1').val()

Comment: Other tips: check your console log. You should get an error because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is the updated code that you need. Changes made in the below code are :

- The image has been hidden by default (Using CSS: display:none;)
- When all the input fields are filled then only the image is displayed
- If you clear any of the fields the image is hidden again using JQuery

Hope, it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Attendees > :input").keyup(function() {
    var $emptyFields = $('.Attendees :input').filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value) === "";
    });

    if (!$emptyFields.length) {
      $(".vinkje").show();
    } else {
      $(".vinkje").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="step1">
  <legend>Step 1</legend>
  <p1>How many people will be attending?</p1>
  <div id="selected_form_code">
    <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">Please choose</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
    <div class="Attendees" id="form1">
      <h2 id="infoNames">Please provide full names:</h2>
      <form action="#" id="form_submit" method="post" name="form_submit">
        <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee1" name="a">
          <label>
                  Attendee 1 name:
          </label>
          <input type="text"> 
        </div>
        <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee1" name="a">
          <label>
                  Attendee 2 name:
          </label>
          <input type="text"> 
        </div>
        <div class="Attendees" id="Attendee1" name="a">
          <label>
                  Attendee 3 name:
          </label>
          <input type="text"> 
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="vinkje" style="display:none"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" height="100" width="100"></p>
</fieldset>
```

Note - (Updated from 5 fields to 3 fields)

Comment: Thanks a lot already for helping me out! now the only thing is, it only checks if the user has chosen 5inputs.

for example if i change the input to 3, the img doesnt show up when all the 3 fields are filled in.. Any thoughts on that?

thanks buddy!

Comment: I think the fault lies somewhere else, if you do change the number of input fields in my code it would still work since it doesn't have to do anything with the number of fields. I'll modify it to 3 fields to show you, it still works.

Comment: i've added the script in my question that i used for the forms.

Answer (score 2):

Create an *event-handler* for `keyup` event for inputs inside the `form`

```
$("form input").on( "change keyup", function(){

  $(this).setAttribute( "data-hasvalue", this.value.trim().length > 0 ); //setting this boolean value to track if value of any input has been set    

  $('.vinkje').toggle( $("form input[data-hasvalue='true']").length > 0 ); //if there is even one input with value, show the image

});
```

**Edit**

In case you want to show image only when all the inputs are filled in, then change it to

```
$("form input").on( "change keyup", function(){

  $(this).setAttribute( "data-hasvalue", this.value.trim().length > 0 ); //setting this boolean value to track if value of any input has been set    

  $('.vinkje').toggle( $("form input[data-hasvalue='true']").length == $("form input").length ); //if there is even one input with value, show the image

});
```

Comment: "But now i have to get an image when all of these inputs are filled in." Your code seems fine but it doesn't go with what the asker has mentioned in the post.

Comment: You've used "$('.vinkje').toggle( $("form input[data-hasvalue='true']").length > 0 );" which will display the image even if any of the fields has been filled, but in the post it has been mentioned to display the image only when all the inputs have been field inside the form like I quoted in my previous comment.

Comment: @HarshitDamani ohh, made the change now.Thanks for pointing out

Comment: No problem at all.